# Parsing a template from an object in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I got a data structure like this

```
var abc = [
              {question: 'Do {{foo}} like <strong>you</strong>?'},
              {question: 'Do {{foo}} like <strong>fruits</strong>?'}
          ];
```

A Template like this

```
<h1>Question</h1>
<span> {{question}} </span>
```

And in my controller something like this:

```
$scope.foo = 'Example',
$scope.question = abc[0].question;
```

As you probably know this does not work.

How could I parse string to a template to use it with variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **ng-bind-html** like:

```
<ng-bind-html
  ng-bind-html="expression">
...
</ng-bind-html>
```

but this require compiling.

Have a look at this directive:
https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile

you can use it this way:

```
<div bind-html-compile="question"></div>
```

Your question will be injected and compiled for you.

Answer (score 1):

Controller:

```
var foo = 'Example';

var abc = [
   {question: 'Do ' + foo + ' like <strong>you</strong>?'},
   {question: 'Do ' + foo + ' like <strong>fruits</strong>?'}
];

$scope.question = abc[0].question;
```

View:

```
<h1>Question</h1>
<span ng-bind-html="question"></span>
```